# Mysql use Cursor for get value from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I want to retrieve data from stored procedure,
this stored procedure returns temp table use engine memory,

example like

```
DECLARE cur_cat CURSOR FOR CALL getSp();
```

Answer (score 0):

A cursor can only use a `select` statement, not a call.

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-cursor.html
It says:

> DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR select_statement

It will **only** allow a select statement, because a stored procedure can return 0, 1 or more resultsets; a `CURSOR` only supports 1 resultset, and MySQL is no way of knowing how amny resultsets a stored procedure will return.

**Workaround**
If your stored procedure returns a resultset, it has a select statement inside.
Extract that select statement and put it in your cursor definition.

```
DECLARE cur_cat CURSOR FOR select_statement_extracted_from_stored_procedure.
```

If you just want to get the data from your stored procedure, use the following code:

**php code sample**

```
$sql = "CALL getsp";
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
if (!$result) { die('error in query'.mysql_error()); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "value is: ".htmlentities($row['field1']);
}
```

Comment: thank's for the answer, but can you give me more detail information about  "select_statement_extracted_from_stored_procedure."
do you mean use some temp table?